# Best Practice of saving an access token in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, security, nsuserdefaults, access-token

I am currently working on an iPhone-App which needs to store an access-token somehow. I am just saving it inside the NSUserdefaults but i dont think it is safest way of  persisting sensitive data like this. So my question now is:

What is the best and safest way of storing data like this on an iOS-Device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am just saving it inside `NSUserDefaults` but I don't think it is the safest way of persisting sensitive data like this.

Almost. `NSUserDefaults` uses plaintext for storing data, so it is insecure. If you want to be a bit safer, you can store the data in the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) (however, even this considered-to-be-secure storage [can be easily dumped](https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper)...)

Comment: Saving access tokens in the `NSUserDefaults` is common practice. As an example you may think of the Facebook iOS SDK.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I agree that it is a common practice. It's just as unsafe as hell. You see, even the keychain can be dumped (I actually used that technique against an annoying person who logged in to Facebook using my iPad. Now I bet she won't do that anymore :P)

Comment: I totally I agree with you. My point is: real-world very common SDKs like Facebook use it and world still has not exploded yet. If the security requirements are not particularly strict I would use the `NSUserDefaults` and sleep well.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yep, "it can be hacked" doesn't mean "everybody will hack it", rather "somebody will hack it".

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Sebastian asked about "the best and safest" way, not the most common way.

Comment: There is no *safe* way. There's ways that are safe **enough**. The answer is perfect, my point is that `NSUserDefaults` are probably safe enough.

Comment: @H2CO3 You should clarify that the "easily dumped" solution requires jailbreaking (i.e., unfettered access to the device). Also, keychain and user defaults are handled differently when backed up, which is the main value of putting stuff in keychain.